# How to create a folder to store files generated in a loop?

Tags: python, loops, directory

I need to do the following in my program:

a) Ask the user to enter the name of a folder to be created in my directory
b) create the folder
c) generate the files inside the folder

The files to be generated are different texts extracted from a book using REGEX. I want the program to loop throughout the REGEX matches and automatically put each match in a file (each text matched in a file). These text files need to be stored in this newly created folder named by the user.

My program creates the folder but only the first text was written to a file inside this new folder. It seems that the error is in the loop. The warning message is:

> Chapter1.txt Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/nataliaresende/Dropbox/PYTHON/word_concatenator_final.py",
>   line 375, in 
>       menu()   File "/Users/nataliaresende/Dropbox/PYTHON/word_concatenator_final.py",
>   line 365, in menu
>       separate_chapters()   File "/Users/nataliaresende/Dropbox/PYTHON/word_concatenator_final.py",
>   line 224, in separate_chapters
>       os.makedirs(folder)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/os.py",
>   line 221, in makedirs
>       mkdir(name, mode) FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/Users/nataliaresende/Dropbox/PYTHON/folder'

Does anyone have an idea of what's going on? Maybe identation?

```
us=input('\n\nEnter the name of the book or file: ')

    pat = re.compile(r'(?<=\[@CHAPST@\]).+?(?=\[@CHAPFN@\])')
    my_chapters=[]


    with open(us, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as file:
        for i in pat.findall(file.read()):
            my_chapters.append(i)

    print('\n\nThis book contains',len(my_chapters), 'chapters')

    user2=input('\n\nWrite chapters to a file? | Y/N: ')


    if user2 =='Y':
    folder_name=input("Name your folder. E.g. 'Texts': ")
    folder=os.path.join('/Users/nataliaresende/Dropbox/PYTHON/', folder_name)
    os.makedirs(folder)

    for j in range(len(my_chapters)):
        chap='Chapter'+str(j+1) +'.txt'.format(folder_name)
        file = os.path.join(folder, chap)

        with open(file, "w") as f:
            for item in my_chapters[j]:
                f.write("%s" % str(item))
        print('\n\n', chap)

print('\n\nChapters 1 -',len(my_chapters), 'written to a file separately. Check your folder named "Chapters" in your directory')
```

Comment: `os.makedirs(folder)` You try to create the same folder more than once. Move that out of the loop and use the [`exist_ok`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs) parameter.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, ok! I moved the os.makedirs(folder) and I have also updated the code. Can you show me the exist_ok parameter?  Maybe updating my code?

Comment: `os.makedirs(folder, exist_ok=True)` Also note, if `user2 != 'Y'`, the `folder` and `folder_name` variables will be undefined.

Comment: what is I add else: continue to the loop?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if that folder exists, and if exists skip creating it:

```
if not os.path.exists(folder):
    os.makedirs(folder)
```

Comment: Replace `os.makedirs(folder)` in your code with my code